# Applying each element of a vector to corresponding dataframe rows in parallel

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, parallel-processing, apply

I have a data frame where the first 3 columns are tag names for the last column, which is a list of matrices. Each of the matrices are binary (only 1's and 0). I would like to pull one of the tag names from each row and replace all values of 1 in the row's matrix with that tag name, but I want to avoid using a loop so that I can do this for all rows in parallel.

Example Dataframe:

```
> df1
   name scenario       Fire
1 name1   scene1 1, 1, 1, 0
2 name2   scene2 0, 1, 0, 1
3 name3   scene3 0, 0, 0, 1

> class(df1$Fire)
[1] "list"

> df1$Fire
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1
```

The target format would look something like this ...

```
> df1$Fire
[[1]]
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] "scene1" "scene1"
[2,] "scene1" "0"     

[[2]]
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] "0"      "0"     
[2,] "scene2" "scene2"

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]    
[1,] "0"  "0"     
[2,] "0"  "scene"
```

I have tried using `apply(df1,1,function)` approach, without success because the resulting output is in a list format rather than gaining the original structure of the df1. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` :

```
df1$Fire <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x == 1, y), df1$Fire, df1$scenario)
df1$Fire

#[[1]]
#     [,1]     [,2]    
#[1,] "scene1" "scene1"
#[2,] "scene1" "0"     

#[[2]]
#     [,1]     [,2]    
#[1,] "0"      "0"     
#[2,] "scene2" "scene2"

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]    
#[1,] "0"  "0"     
#[2,] "0"  "scene3"
```

**data**

Usually it is better if you add data in a reproducble form using `dput` so that we don't have to construct it from scratch.

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("name1", "name2", "name3"), scenario = c("scene1",
"scene2", "scene3"), Fire = list(structure(c(1, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L)), structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1),.Dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(0, 
0, 0, 1),.Dim = c(2L, 2L)))),row.names = c("1", "2", "3"),class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Ronak, my apologies for making you create the object from scratch. I have never used `dput()` to condense my code before, especially because I usually work from my local PC, so I usually use `saveRDS()` and provide the file. Is there an advantage to `dput()`? After experimenting with it it seems to provide a path that uses my local directories, which would not be much help if I posted it in this thread.

Comment: You need to use `dput` after loading the data into R. `dput` does not give path to local directories. It should give you output  as what I have at the end of my answer. When you copy that and paste it in the console you exactly recreate the object `df1` in your R environment. Also read [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)